# Spring MVC:Request method 'GET' not supported,DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I test a very simple Spring MVC example .code:
 */

```
@Controller
public class TestResponse {


@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/test/emp/1", 
        headers="Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody Employee getEmp() {
Employee e = new Employee("ad", "asdad");
System.out.println("Hello World");
return e;
}   
}
```

and I test it through web browser..405!
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported was thrown...
anyone can tell me how to fix it...and why?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public class TestResponse {


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/emp/1", 
            headers="Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Employee getEmp() {
    Employee e = new Employee("ad", "asdad");
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    return e;
    }   
}
```

Please give this a try.

Note the inclusion of a @RequestMapping at the class level.

Comment: Hi there, I think the problem might be that your client (i.e., the browser) is not setting the "Acccept=application/json" header when making the request to the server. I use a free tool called "RESTClient" for testing my RESTful WS. You can set custom headers using that tool. Give it a try. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks you r right...Browser is not a good tool to test Restful URL...I remove the headers="Accept=application/json" it works in browser...